# Force Blazor component to rerender when url query changes

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

Everything I've read points me to using NavigationManager.LocationChanged event, however that does not detect when only the query string changes. Therefore, nothing fires.

I've tried what is suggested [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/28457) and that does not do what I am looking for.

I need my component to rerender everytime the query parameters in the current route changes. Has anyone been able to do this?

UPDATE:

Here is my code example:

```
@page "/accounts"

@if (Accounts != null)
{
    <table>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var account in Accounts)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <NavLink href="/accounts/?accountId={account.AccountId}">@Account.Name</NavLink>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}

@if (Account != null)
{
    <div>
        <h2>@Account.Name</h2>
    </div>
}

@implements IDisposable
@inject NavigationManger NavManager
@inject AccountService AccountService

@code {
    protected Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGid();
    protected Guid AccountId { get; set; } = Guid.Empty;
    protected List<AccountModel> Accounts { get; set; }
    protected AccountModel Account { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        NavManager.LocationChanged += LocationChanged;
    }

    protected async override Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        if (AccountId != Guid.Empty)
        {
            Account = await AccountService.GetAsync(AccountId);
        }
        else
        {
            Accounts = await AccountService.GetAllAsync();
        }
    
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    void LocationChanged(object sender, LocationChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    
        StateHasChanged();
    }
    
    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        NavManager.LocationChanged -= LocationChanged;
    }
}
```

The problem here is `LocationChanged(object, LocationChangedEventArgs)` does not fire when only the query parameters change. Which makes sense, the route is the same `/accounts`.

Bascically I have one page to show a list of Accounts and view a single account. I want the route to be `/accounts` when view the list and '/accounts?accountId=someAccountId' to be the route when im viewing one. Using standard NavLink component does not trigger a rerender of the component and neither does the LocationChanged event. Not even with setting a new Id value. Seeing as to how `StateHasChanged` only rerenders the component if a value has changed.

Comment: Are your query string values properties annotated with the `[SupplyParameterFromQuery]` attribute?  That's required to get those properties to update and have your `OnParametersSet` method called (or its async variant).

Comment: Provide a [mre]

Comment: @KirkWoll I'm on .NET 5, I see that is a .NET 6 feature? I cannot upgrade yet.

Comment: @HenkHolterman example added.

Comment: You could store the initial query string parameter into the `ProtectedLocalStorage` or `ProtectedSessionStorage` when the applications initially loads. When the page is re-submitted with a new query string you could compare it to the storage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up getting what I wanted to happen work like this:

```
@page "/accounts"

@if (Accounts != null)
{
    <table>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var account in Accounts)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <NavLink href="/accounts/?accountId={account.AccountId}">@Account.Name</NavLink>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}

@if (Account != null)
{
    <div>
        <h2>@Account.Name</h2>
    </div>
}

@implements IDisposable
@inject NavigationManger NavManager
@inject AccountService AccountService

@code {
    protected Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGid();
    protected Guid AccountId { get; set; } = Guid.Empty;
    protected List<AccountModel> Accounts { get; set; }
    protected AccountModel Account { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        NavManager.LocationChanged += LocationChanged;
    }

    protected async override Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        if (AccountId != Guid.Empty)
        {
            Account = await AccountService.GetAsync(AccountId);
        }
        else
        {
            Accounts = await AccountService.GetAllAsync();
        }
    
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    async void LocationChanged(object sender, LocationChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (AccountId != Guid.Empty)
        {
            Account = await AccountService.GetAsync(AccountId);
        }
        else
        {
            Accounts = await AccountService.GetAllAsync();
        }
    
        StateHasChanged();
    }
    
    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        NavManager.LocationChanged -= LocationChanged;
    }
}
```

I ended up just calling all the same code I want to run on a first render manually. I was hoping (falsely assuming) that I could tell it to just rereun the component lifecycle from the top automatically by changing one local property and then calling `StateHasChanged`.

Now when I toggle between `"/accounts"` and `"/accounts?accountId=someId"` the component rerenders as I want.

Comment: Good, but you could have called a common method rather than repeating the code twice.

Comment: Maybe this would be enough:    
void LocationChanged(object sender, LocationChangedEventArgs e) => NavManager.NavigateTo(NavManager.Uri, true);

Answer (score 1):

I do this in a wasm app works well

set this on your page where you want to receive the route parameter

```
@page "/pagename/{text?}"

<div>@Text</div>
```

then

```
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string? Text { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Text = Text ?? "fantastic";
    }
    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        Text = Text  ?? "Name Not Supplied";
    }
}
```

The will re-render any data changes, AFAIK you can't force a component to re-render without reloading it, only the changed subscribers, which makes sense, as re-renders are expensive.

[Doc's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0) look under router parameters

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the StateHasChanged() to the function/logic which changes your query string, which will re-render your component.

Comment: I've tried that but StateHasChanged only happens IF a value in the component has changed. I updated my question with an example to show where I am trying that and it doesn't work.